# Is 'if' equal to 'should'?

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

I found a sentence.

> Please do not hesitate to contact me **should** you have any questions.

In this sentence the word 'should' has connected two sentences. I want to know the usage or the meaning and what this 'should' express in this sentence. Is equal to "if" ? If it is so, is it a way of more formal or awkward, unofficial ?
*Please do not hesitate to contact me if ( instead of *should*) you have any questions.*

How can the word 'should' connect two sentences as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in this context 'if' and 'should' are equivalent (which is the word I think you wanted, instead of 'equal').

> If it is so, is it a way of more formal or awkward, unofficial?

I would say that not it is actually informal to use 'if' in the sentence above -- it's a professional way to phrase that question. 'Should' makes it more formal, but I would argue that it's a pretty subtle nuance. It's a question of tone rather than meaning: 'should' reads as more reserved than 'if'.

Comment: You're welcome Débora, I'm glad to have helped.